# Joining three views and using variables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have joined 3 views together to reflect a summary of each view per period

When trying to use 'MC Total' to summarize all 3 it is reflecting as an integer

Have tried multiple options to no avail

---

Below are the results returned

```
period_start_date|period_end_date|MC| D/MC|N/MC|MC/Total
2019-08-01|2019-08-15|1,136.99|3,375.77|0|4
```

---

- Tried with no IF statements
- Tried with sub queries
- Tried with sub queries and IF statements
- Tried formatting 'MC Total'
- Tried without variables

---

```sql
SELECT
m.`period_start_date`,
m.`period_end_date`,
@meta := IF(m.`Net Collections` IS NOT NULL,m.`Net Collections`,0) AS 'MC',
@dnf := IF(d.`Metacorp Net`IS NOT NULL,d.`Metacorp Net`,0) as 'D/MC',
@nmrc:= IF(n.`Metacorp Net`IS NOT NULL,d.`Metacorp Net`,0) as 'N/MC',
@meta+@dnf+@nmrc AS 'MC Total'
FROM collectionsmax.mc_period_trust_summary m
RIGHT OUTER JOIN collectionsmax.dnf_period_trust_summary d
ON m.`period_start_date` = d.`period_start_date`
LEFT OUTER JOIN collectionsmax.nmrc_period_trust_summary n
ON  m.`period_start_date` = n.`period_start_date`

GROUP BY m.`period_start_date` ,m.`period_end_date`;
```

---

## screenshot

[image]

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN (just sayin') and spaces in table/column identifiers is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are using `if` or variables.  Use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT m.period_start_date, m.period_end_date,
       COALESCE(m.`Net Collections`, 0) AS `MC`,
       COALESCE(d.`Metacorp Net`, 0) as `D/MC`,
       COALESCE(n.`Metacorp Net`, 0) as `N/MC`,
       (COALESCE(m.`Net Collections`, 0) +
        COALESCE(d.`Metacorp Net`, 0) +
        COALESCE(n.`Metacorp Net`, 0) 
       ) as `MC Total`
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the response, this returned the same value of 4. I only used IF's and variables as I exhausted other means.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one reason why you shouldn't use spaces as table/column identifiers. It may seem a little contrived by this sort of thing happens...:

```
CREATE TABLE `more stuff`(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE more (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO more VALUES (2),(4),(6),(8);
INSERT INTO `more stuff` VALUES (1),(3),(5),(7);

SELECT * FROM `more stuff`;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  3 |
|  5 |
|  7 |
+----+

SELECT * FROM more stuff;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
|  4 |
|  6 |
|  8 |
+----+
```